# Perl <<EOP is generating an indent before the reCapctha box. How do I get rid of it?

Tags: html, perl

I have the following code in my reCapctha.pm file and it is resulting in an indent of the capctha box to the left. I have double checked by html files more than 10 time and there is no reason for the indent there. So I am assuming following code is responsible specially the `<<EOP` part.

I am not very good with perl can some one please help me get rid of this indent/space? It really looks unprofessional for a landing page the way it is. Thanks in advance for your help.

```
sub get_html
{
my ($self,$pubkey) = @_;
my $html = <<EOP
<script type="text/javascript">
var RecaptchaOptions = {theme: 'red'};
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k=$pubkey"> </script>
EOP
;
}
```

Comment: Your analysis of the problem doesn't make sense. The assignment creates a variable named $html but doesn't do anything with it.

Comment: Sorry, the code I pasted here was just the part that I thought contain the issue. i also see the following.

    `sub _html { shift->{_html} ||= HTML::Tiny->new }`

    `sub get_options_setter {`
    `my $self = shift;`
    `my $options = shift || return '';`

    `croak "The argument to get_options_setter must be a hashref"`
    `unless 'HASH' eq ref $options;`
    `my $h = $self->_html;`
    `return $h->script(`
    `{ type => 'text/javascript' },`
    `"\n//<![CDATA[\n"`
    `. "var RecaptchaOptions = "`
    `. $h->json_encode( $options )`
    `. ";\n//]]>\n"`
    `) . "\n";`
    `}

Comment: @Avon You should put that code in the question, not in the comments.

Comment: Still doesn't help clarify the issue, only complicates it. Try to create a page with just the reCaptcha; if that still has the problem, post it in full; but I suspect it will not.

Comment: @Avon That code does not call the routine `get_html()`

Answer (score 0):

If you have something like

```
my $foo = <<'__EOI__';
   foo
   bar
__EOI__
```

You can remove the leading spaces using

```
$foo =~ s/^\s+//mg;
```

You could even combine the stripping and the assignment.

```
( my $foo = <<'__EOI__' ) =~ s/^\s+//mg;
   foo
   bar
__EOI__
```

Comment: What would be the difference in EOI and EOP bin this case...google does not return much on these!

Comment: None whatsoever, it's just an arbitrary label, just like Perl doesn't care what you call your variables.

Comment: Leading whitespace in a here document doesn't appear to have with the problem to do; I intetpret the question to mean there is unwanted indentation in a piece of HTML generated by basically some other part of the code, or the JavaScript it pulls in.

Comment: @tripleee, The generated HTML is surely output via `document.write`, so the space that needs to be removed is the space before the `<script>`, and that's likely the spaces at the beginning of the heredoc lines he didn't show, and that's the spaces I showed how to remove.

Comment: @Avon Jay, The name is arbitrary. I use `__EOI__`, but feel free to use `EOP` or `EOI` if that's what you want.

Comment: @ikegami: HTML doesn't care about spaces in the source, and there are none in the code anyway; and it's fairly clear the OP doesn't know what's going on.

Comment: @tripleee, HTML does care about spaces between tags (other than a lone newline) and you're arguing a lot against something you don't know won't help.